# Is there a way to load a replacement CSS file if and only if another CSS file is not found?

Tags: html, css

The concept is simple, I want to include a css file in my webpage. However, if that css is not found (for whatever reason) I want to include a *different* css file.

I can't just include both files, because they have rules unique to each file that won't be overwritten and will interact with each other in an undesirable way.

Comment: create a condition using Js to search for the first css, if not found load your new css file

Comment: Are you willing to do some JavaScript or css only

Comment: @fxtrot I'd like to avoid using javascript if possible because I'm going to have to implement this change on hundreds of files and I'd like it to be a simple search-and-replace once I get it figured out, and I want to avoid any big performance hits, but if there is no other way than so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mightFail.css" onerror="this.href = 'replacement.css'">
```

Comment: this.href will replace the href of the link itself?

Comment: Yes. `this` is the element with `onerror`, and `href` just sets it. You could also use `this.setAttribute('href', 'replacement.css`);`